# Post variable before redirect?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I am currently building on a CMS. I want to send a page-id or site-id to the next page on redirect. I tried doing it using the jQuery POST function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sender').on('click','a',function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    var n = url.indexOf('#')+1;
                    var siteid = url.substr(n,url.length);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'pages.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { siteid:siteid },
                        success: function(response){
                                console.log('check'); 
                        },
                        error: function(){
                                console.log('error');
                        }
                    });
                });
});
```

But because the request is sent at the same time as the redirect, it does not seems to work.

Because I am using the apache rewrite_engine to redirect stuff, I cannot use GET.

Apart from session_variables, what are my options?
I want to keep it safe, so I don't want much info to be visible/available!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to wait for the AJAX request to complete *before* the page is redirected. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sender').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the default redirect
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var n = url.indexOf('#') + 1;
        var siteid = url.substr(n, url.length);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'pages.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                siteid: siteid 
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log('check'); 
                window.location.assign(url); // redirect once the AJAX has successfully completed
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to clearly understand why you need but I think this can answer your problem.

If what you need is to transfert informations using a real POST method, just create an hidden form with `method="POST"` and fill it on click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sender').on('click','a',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var n = url.indexOf('#')+1;
        var siteid = url.substr(n,url.length);

        $('input[name="siteid"]').val(siteid);
        $('#redirectForm').submit();
    });
});
</script>

<form id="redirectForm" action="pages.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="siteid" value=""/>
</form>
```